# pull-right not working in IE-9 and IE-8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Link to JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TomHagen/smnpg7ua/1/

```
<td class="lastCol">    
    View Detail     
    <div id="div2">                     
        <input type="button" class="lightGrayButton btn btn-mini btn-primary pull-right cartButton atc" value="Select Plan">
    </div>                          
</td>
```

The above code in jsfiddle works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE browsers, the View detail is aligned to the right and Select Plan is in the left.

I tried removing pull-right, having pull-right along with the div tag, having a new div for pull-right but nothing seem to be working.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use Bootstrap, but I don't see that you are loading the bootstrap CSS file. Try adding this as an external resource: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Added the bootstrap.css file

Comment: @Stalwart, can you re-link the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smnpg7ua/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think its working fine in IE9 but not in IE8. The problem with your that `pull-right` and other `col*` in bootstrap 3 is that they make extensive use of media queries to make floats and columns responsive.

Its suggested that you do not use bootstrap if you want to support IE8 but if you must, you can add [link](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)

```
<script src="assets/js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

and it will fix your issues.